# Function to save Variables monthly to a text-file

Tags: php, counter, hit

I am working on a HitCounter for my website. I want to add some monthly statistics. On my "info.php" I can access to all relevant variables, like:

```
$totalhits, $visits, $botcount
```

Now I want to add a function which stores these variables to a .txt-file, when a new month begins. Also I would like to reset the content from the .txt-files which contain my Hits, IPs and stuff.

It doesnt really matter if the function is started on the 1st, 2nd or within the first week so it's okay to me that the script is started manually by accessing my info.php.

I am pretty new to php, but I think about some "if/else"-function which checks the current month and if there is already a text-file, for e.g. '9-16.txt' then the function should break. If there is no such file, it should create one and store the variables to it.

**Edit**: This one worked for me. The function 'archive()' had to be put on the end of my 'info.php', because I worked with exit in the if-statement:
So the script checks if there is a file with the "month" in the name - if not, it creates one. If there is already one, it returns.

```
<?php 
     function archive($a, $b, $c)
     {
     #format 'mm-yy'
     $datename = date('m-Y');
        if (file_exists('archiv/'.$datename.'.txt')) {
            return;
        } else {
            $file = fopen('archiv/'.$datename.'.txt', 'w');
            fwrite($file, $a);
            fwrite($file, $b);
            fwrite($file, $c);
        }
     }
?>
```

Comment: This reads like a list of product requires, not a question. What problem are you having? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Seems like he's having a logical problem. I believe your solution is one that will work (an if/esle function which checks the current month and if there is already a text-file....) Take a read up on the [Date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and have a read up on [how fopen/fwrite work](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: Thank you for you answers. I will check your links. @Quentin: You're right. I didnt do it on purpose. Thank you!

Comment: `"No such file or directory"`: does the directory exist, and does Apache have the rights to create files in it?

Comment: I edited to quick I guess: I created the folder in the wrong path; everything works now. Thank you for your answers - it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me. So the script checks if there is a file with the "month" in the name - if not, it creates one. If there is already one, it returns.

```
<?php 
 function archive($a, $b, $c)
 {
 #format 'mm-yy'
 $datename = date('m-Y');
    if (file_exists('archiv/'.$datename.'.txt')) {
        return;
    } else {
        $file = fopen('archiv/'.$datename.'.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($file, $a);
        fwrite($file, $b);
        fwrite($file, $c);
    }
 }
?>
```